# onMessageReceived only called in Service but not in Activity

Tags: android, wear-os

onMessageReceived is only called in WearabeListenerService.
If I dont use a service and just register my Activity as MessageApi listener
onMessageReceived is not called.
I register the listener as following:

```
   if (!mConnection.isConnected()) {
            phoneConnectionError();
        } else {
            Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mConnection, this).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    Log.d("Viera","Add listener success: "+status.isSuccess());
                }
            });
    }
```

The status is allways success.
What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: As requested, here is more Activity code:

Edit2: Added more code

```
    public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity
          implements ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>, MessageApi.MessageListener {



        private BoxInsetLayout mContainerView;
        private String nodeId;
        private GoogleApiClient mConnection;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mContainerView = (BoxInsetLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

            mConnection = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Wearable.API)
                    .build();
            setAmbientEnabled();
            retrieveDeviceNode();
        }


        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
            Log.d("Viera","Recieved: "+messageEvent.getPath());
            if (messageEvent.getPath().equals("tvException")) {
                tvException();
            }
        }



        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Wearable.MessageApi.removeListener(mConnection, this);
            mConnection.disconnect();
        }


        private void afterNodeSearch() {

            if (nodeId == null || !mConnection.isConnected()) {
                phoneConnectionError();
            } else {
                Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mConnection, this).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Log.d("Viera","Add listener success: "+status.isSuccess());
                    }
                });
                //... some other stuff here
            }

        }



        // I know I should to this useig an other API but I know I am connected to the right node 
        // because the Id's here and on mobile device matches
        private void retrieveDeviceNode() {
            findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.content).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mConnection.blockingConnect();
                    NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result =
                            Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mConnection).await();
                    List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                    if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                        nodeId = nodes.get(0).getId();
                    }
                    afterNodeSearch();
                }
            }).start();
        }

  @Override
    public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
        if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            phoneConnectionError();
        } else {
            Log.d("Viera", "Send successfull!");
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (nodeId == null) {
            retrieveDeviceNode();
        } else if (!mConnection.isConnected()) {
            connect();
        } else {
            String command = v.getTag().toString();
            sendCommand(COMMAND, command);
        }
    }

    private final static String COMMAND = "onCommand", START_APP = "startApp";

    private void sendCommand(final String command, final String msg) {
        if (nodeId != null) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mConnection.isConnected()) {
                        byte[] msgBytes = null;
                        if (msg != null) msg.getBytes();
                        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mConnection, nodeId, command, msgBytes).setResultCallback(MainActivity.this);
                    } else {
                        phoneConnectionError();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Yu should be able to register your activity as a message listener. Can you reproduce this in a small activity and share the code here?

Comment: @AliNaddaf ok, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found my problems:

I was using the wrong keys! The signature of the wearable and the mobile app were different!

It sees that I ALWAYS will get notifyed in a WerableListenerService when a Message is sent, even with different signature BUT not in a Listener registered using Wearable.MessageApi.addListener.

This means my code was correct, but my building was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, you are building a GoogleApiClient (what you called mConnection) but you never connected that (i.e. never called mConnection.connect()). In addition, when you build your GoogleApiClient, you also need to define two listeners (could be your activity); one for receiving successful connection callbacks and one for failures. In the one for a successful connection, there is an onConnected() callback that you should be using to add your MessageApi listeners, etc. If you look at any of the sample projects for Wear on our GitHub repo, you will see how all of these can be done.

Comment: I am calling blockingConnect which connects the Client. Also I am able to send messages to my phone.

Comment: Please share the code that sends message to your device as well.

Comment: ok, I added the code to send messages which works. Messages are recevived with a service on the phone.

Comment: There should be two different activities involved in your application, one on the phone side (which you expect to receive messages) and one on the watch (which I presume is sending the messages) however I do not see the two in your code, you only have one WearableActivity (which shows your watch side?)